# Does make sense using exotic bootstrap in GCC?

Tags: compiling, gcc

Has anyone any evidence that currently GCC is bootstrapped in non trivial ways to detect bugs for certain features and architectures? Or at least point to some documentation where I can find wich real bootstrap tecniques are used to check for bugs in GCC?

**Regular bootstrap**

- Use GCC version (X-1) to compile GCC version (X), call that **A**
- **A** is the new compiler with slow binary.
- Use the new compiler **A** to compile itself and produce **B**
- **B** is the new compiler with fast binary
- let **B** compile itself and produce **C**
- At this point if **A** is bug free, then binary dump of produced executable of **B** and **C** should be the same.

The GCC approach is too keep code features used when developing to a minimum so that if bootstrap succed you know that at least minimal set of features is bug free. (Opposed to Clang where a greater number of features is used just to increase the coverage by simply bootstrapping).

**Profile guided optimization boostrap**

- Use **A** to compile itself using the `-fprofile-generate` flag and produce **B**
- Use **B** to compile itself (it will generate profile info)
- Use **A** to compile itslef using the `-fprofile-use` and produce **B'**
- Use **B'** to compile itself using the `-fprofile-generate` flag and produce **C**
- Use **C** to compile itself (it will generate profile info)
- Use **B'** to compile itslef using the `-fprofile-use` and produce **C'**
- At this point if **A** is bug free, then binary dump of produced executable of **B'** and **C'** should be the same.

**Backward and forward bootstrap**

- Use GCC version X to compile GCC version (X-1) and produce **A**
- Then start a regular bootstrap for **A**
- Use A to compile GCC version X and produce **D**
- Do a regular bootstrap on **D**.

Off topic:
I think it would be nice if someone create a graph of GCC bootstraps keeping into account special bootstraps (like cross-platform builds), and see where bootstraps fails and quickly